# In your experience, what's the difference between a great QA director and a good one?

Tags: career-development, management

We all have discussed-to-death what makes someone a 10x software developer, or a great programming team lead. But what makes someone a better-than-average QA director?

What's your ideal QA boss?

Answer (score 3):

What I think that QA Director/Manager should be.

- Should know the fundamental and also how really the QA works in real life.
- Understand how process of testing and how important the double checking, documentation and etc, no matter how busy it became.
- Even he/she is not technical, he/she should find ways to let the QA members grows into something that the world are requiring them to be.
- As much as possible, he/she should at least defend his/her members in times of trouble. Even to the higher ups.
- Does not give in to the higher ups request, in times of crammed time especially during the time of releasing the system. Usually QA will become a bottleneck, especially if the development will be delivered late, but what other see is that the QA are the one's at fault and no one will justify it even the QA Director.
- If he/she is technical person and have a great experience in manual testing, it will be really great.
- Does not shot down one's ideas just because it does not give him/her benefits.